# Console Attach File - Done button closes tab instead of returning to parent

Tags: case, attachment, service-cloud-console, console

In the Console, if I attach a File to a Case, the Done button does not return you to that Case. I realized the URL does not have the `retURL` set like it does in a classic, internal app view. So I manually opened a tab like that and it still does not respect a `retURL` or `saveURL` parameter. It always closes the tab, leaving the user having to re-search for the object they were working on.

Has anyone found any workarounds to this? I assumed I could just pass the retURL value into the URL, or add `isdtp=vw`, but that didn't work. I tried an iFrame of this page, hoping I could cover the "Done" button with a custom one, but I couldn't get around same-source origin. I'm out of options except to custom code the entire attachments screen, which I really don't want to do.

Comment: Caleb, I checked in my developer org in a classic console app. The Attach File button in attachment related list opens a new subtab for uploading files and after clicking done, closes the tab and focuses back on the case tab. Can you explain a more about what different behavior are you experiencing.

Comment: @manjit_singh I realized that our org had been overriding the Attach File button in an attempt to solve a different issue: when using the out of box Attach Files, it opens it in a new subtab like you said, so the parent tab does not refresh to reflect that an Attachment was added. It appears this is ultimately the problem I need to solve. Here's a whole thread all about that -> https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000AujTIAS